# dell latitude e5450 keyboard issues

Tags: 14.04

A brand new Dell Latitude E5450, with a fresh installation of Ubuntu 14.04 Sometimes a pressed key repeats until another key is pressed. This is presumably a BIOS bug.
my BIOS version A06

Comment: Can you be sure it's not just that a key is stuck which is interrupted when another key is pressed (so hardware rather than OS)

Comment: sure it not hardware issue

Answer (score 0):

update bios Version A12 fix this issues (Ubuntu 14.04 Sometimes a pressed key repeats issues)

http://www.dell.com/support/home/bb/en/bbbsdt1/Drivers/DriversDetails?driverId=NMRC0